# Prevent output cache when the result is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

In my project I use the OutputCache attribute so my web server doesn't have to keep downloading the same files, but rarely there are some issues where for unknown reasons it returns null.

So If the result is null I don't want to cache the result is there a simple way to do this?

```
    [OutputCache(VaryByParam = "path", Duration = 6000)]
    public ActionResult LoadCachedFile(string path)
    {
        var result = DownloadFile(path);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something similar to what nikstffrs suggested, but instead of overriding OnActionExecuted I used OnResultExecuting.

```
public class CustomOutputCache : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!(filterContext.Result is EmptyResult))
           base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a class inheriting from OutputCacheAttribute overriding the

```
OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
```

method. Here's a little sample code:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class CustomOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result != null)
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: As I was returning null the filterContext.Result was not null but a System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult object, so I changed the if condition to `if(!(filterContext.Result is EmptyResult))` But even after this it still was not working, even when it didn't call base.OnActionExecuted it was still being cached and the next request to the same url would not hit my action

Comment: Worked when I used OnResultExecuting instead